# C# Help filling DataTables with foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, datatable, dataset

In Visual Studio Designer, I have created a DataSet that has 2 DataTables; `EmployeeDT` and `PayrollSheetDT` which pull data from SQL Server via SELECT statements. The two DataTables have a relation via the `SSN` column.

Relevant SQL Server database structure:

- Table: `Employee`, columns: `SSN` (primary key), `Driver`
- Table: `PayrollSheet`, columns: `SSN` (foreign key), `PSDate`

In my PayrollSheet form, I have multiple combo boxes where I have bound DataSource, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the `EmployeeDT` DataTable. When I start the program, I am successful in clicking the down arrow in the "Driver" combobox, choosing a drivers name, and having the other comboboxes display information from that Driver / SQL record - as they are bound to the same DataSource.

I also have a listbox next to the comboboxes, with the goal of displaying the `PSDate` for whatever `SSN` is selected in the comboboxes.

The listbox is my issue. I need to be able to change the value in any combobox, and have the PSDate displayed in the listbox. I don't know if this can be done, as the `PayrollSheetDT` DataTable executes a static SQL query, but what I'm wanting would be the equivalent of adding a `WHERE SSN = <selected ssn in other datatable>`

I don't have a good understanding of how to do this, but if I try to fill the `TableAdapter`, I get the following error:

> *One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.*

Thanks for your help

Comment: You were 100% right, PSDate was marked as NOT NULL in the SQL database.  Once that was fixed, everything worked as expected.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

These things are VERY finickly.

That error could mean a few things. Try to (temporarily) delete the PayrollSheet table and only populate the Employee table.

Make sure your column names match the sql query, like the short words/phrases for the column names are exact matches.  EmployeeLastName is not the same as EmployeeLName.

Make sure there is not an "extra" PayrollSheet row that doesn't have a parent row (back to Employee), aka, an orphan row in PayrollSheet.

Here is a generic helper. Try to populate a DataSet object (just "DataSet", not a strongly typed one)...and then do a ds.WriteXml(@"C:\myds.xml") and then go through that xml and make sure the column names match.

Also..check datatypes. Check that a column (in the ds definition) isn't marked as "not null" and then the query returns a null value for some row. It's some kind of tick tack issue, I'm pretty sure.

99x out of 100x, when I had this issue, it was something tiny tiny that screwed me.

Comment: There is also a `GetErrors()` method on `DataTable`s that returns rows with errors including a message (after calling `Adapter.Fill()`) - it's just a verbose message without error codes but still you can get an idea where the problem is emerging from